# Codeigniter is cutting off the strings in my database results

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am running Codeigniter 3.0.6 and storing strings(all in hex) in a SQLServer 2012 database.  The problem I am having is when Codeigniter returns my data from the database anything exceeding 255 characters is being cut off. Anyone got any ideas?

Strings in database (Correct Length):

```
1: 2AAF97C27B86C3F84153D2A85D08B0B0581B63D1F527C522F64604C344E098FDCFBBEC1C5660E0A496ABDAFC6EDFA2315AB9ACC45AB528688C20A262C247E820CC365288EC9C0A30EC96AC2B9262E20CAD9D8AB118A2DAF4A0637FFF0F8E008555AE7C6C809E94B04F5291B1E36757BAC9DBBEBE2E00AEE642638AA09115FFC671C8FEF03547F36752C4DD65204EE1AE
2: 95586157B50472C6408332AD6F80008A05DAF3700560442414963503FEE86D8CA585B603E4431EFE6BDACC5438FF9CD8F6954065FC02A825604E3644541E9CB0B5A9716FA832E79C418DF9BEC07A8F8822F64F9E7ECB47ED72B91EE11E1271FFBCD74BB4A81FE53E10E1746EE556B4C7E3ADBB1462E51AFAB03317A559DBFCEA76E94AF0E563182C4B9A5BA62BB7C5EC
3: 77E13F477905549B3782F86755DD95FA3675FD3D8C11048032E589579DA27D2EDA9516ADBF6268160E96D59D0023EF2D510E0024965EECA018C98CA9D2C6655BA2AC17EEBE5F1E511957B7371FF538ABFD5CFFDF8B92389547AA5A65C698B9709A5B994140924907FA8D0B0EB30A17A7AD2F4FD38C583A1461B9A8CBA9BA3DFE1D0AD1731DAFF96A3CCA3BD9AD18B541
4: ADE25DF92667516294106E4A8F72B892FC6EB43AA64982C74DA157077366A697F16B8D6422659F2ABD0CBE6617D8AD556CE5F4143B18E2D6A744B2D55FADAEB93BB229DB79375C7AF2E7D2B4EACD905EF13C737DB5B04964F9726A849D08BA3EBE92D0BC909DD7F84361D566F9B99AC8EAF13E29555215A3B1E3BE99CA4AF34894AC4961975D33548C8EBFA91E15C9E5
```

Strings returned in Codeigniter (Cut to length of 255):

```
1: 2AAF97C27B86C3F84153D2A85D08B0B0581B63D1F527C522F64604C344E098FDCFBBEC1C5660E0A496ABDAFC6EDFA2315AB9ACC45AB528688C20A262C247E820CC365288EC9C0A30EC96AC2B9262E20CAD9D8AB118A2DAF4A0637FFF0F8E008555AE7C6C809E94B04F5291B1E36757BAC9DBBEBE2E00AEE642638AA09115FFC
2: 95586157B50472C6408332AD6F80008A05DAF3700560442414963503FEE86D8CA585B603E4431EFE6BDACC5438FF9CD8F6954065FC02A825604E3644541E9CB0B5A9716FA832E79C418DF9BEC07A8F8822F64F9E7ECB47ED72B91EE11E1271FFBCD74BB4A81FE53E10E1746EE556B4C7E3ADBB1462E51AFAB03317A559DBFCE
3: 77E13F477905549B3782F86755DD95FA3675FD3D8C11048032E589579DA27D2EDA9516ADBF6268160E96D59D0023EF2D510E0024965EECA018C98CA9D2C6655BA2AC17EEBE5F1E511957B7371FF538ABFD5CFFDF8B92389547AA5A65C698B9709A5B994140924907FA8D0B0EB30A17A7AD2F4FD38C583A1461B9A8CBA9BA3DF
4: ADE25DF92667516294106E4A8F72B892FC6EB43AA64982C74DA157077366A697F16B8D6422659F2ABD0CBE6617D8AD556CE5F4143B18E2D6A744B2D55FADAEB93BB229DB79375C7AF2E7D2B4EACD905EF13C737DB5B04964F9726A849D08BA3EBE92D0BC909DD7F84361D566F9B99AC8EAF13E29555215A3B1E3BE99CA4AF34
```

Database Table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A user commented in the [api documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-fetch-array.php):

> Note that if you fetch varchar fields larger than 255 letters the
>   result will be cut off at 255 letters.
>
> To prevent this you have to do a CONVERT(TEXT,data_field) for this
>   fields in your select clause.

Basically, just use MSSQL's CONVERT() function on the fields you want to return. Might not be ideal as you're probably using active record, but it's what you'll have to deal with as mssql support is wonky at best.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TEXT` data type to store large strings (65,535 bytes).